# map.js background not always loading, suggestions to make it more consistent?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, background

I have a google map background on one of the pages to [my website](http://thirdprinciple.com) through javascript, but I noticed it doesn't always load. Instead part of it will appear as a small square in the upper lefthand corner (as if it stop while tiling the page). If I refresh my screen or even resize my window, it will load and then I can't recreate the problem for a while.

It happens most consistently when first visiting the website, obviously a problem for new visitors we want to attract the website.

Any ideas on making it load better? Or ideas on what the problem is?

Code:

```
/*
    Global
    */
    var map;

    function initialize() {

        /*
        Basic Setup
        */

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.726020913196265, -105.00015970000004);

        var myOptions = {
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            draggable: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,     //disable zooming
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 16,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //   ROADMAP; SATELLITE; HYBRID; TERRAIN;
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        /*
        MARKER
        */

        /*
        //for custom image
        var image = 'yourflag.png';
        icon: image 

        //for animation marker drop
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

        */
        var markerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.726020913196265, -105.00015970000004);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerlatlng,
            title:"Hello World!"
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        /*
        INFO Bubble
        */

        myInfoWindowOptions = {
            content: '',
            maxWidth: 275
        };

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(myInfoWindowOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(){
            infoWindow.close();
        });

        infoWindow.open(map,marker);


    }//end initialize


    /*
    onLoad
    */
    $(function(){
        initialize();

        $("#zo").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            map.setZoom( map.getZoom()-1 );
            //map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(9.825183,15.1975769));
        });

        $("#zi").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            map.setZoom( map.getZoom()+1 );
        });

        $("#gt").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var lt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.114739, -115.171840);
            //map.setZoom( 16 );
            map.panTo(lt1);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I love the scrolling effect of the page, but looking at the code and the page source, I can't completely tell how your onload event fires. I too sometimes had problems with certain pages not loading completely on certain browsers.

Have you tried attaching multiple events to load the background?

```
        function doLoad() {  // this is what executes when page is to load
             initialize();
        }
        //different event handlers for page load
        if ( window.addEventListener ) { 
              window.addEventListener( "load", doLoad, false );
        }
        else if ( window.attachEvent ) { 
              window.attachEvent( "onload", doLoad );
        } 
        else  if ( window.onLoad ) {
              window.onload = doLoad;
        }
        else window.setTimeout('doLoad', 1000);
```

Comment: That's @EliteOctagon! Sorry for the disappearing...long story short I ended up moving to New York and that was a whole thing. 

BUT I still want to get this resolved. I'm not the best developer (aka, novice), how and where would I implement your code?